# i am getting unwanted rounded border in safari only

Tags: html, css, safari

Please see image you will see a thin border behind the main border inside chrome and firefox everything is smooth but inside safari and iPhone we encounte round thin border
how to remove it and why this happening please help.[image]

Comment: Could you please post your HTML + CSS?

Comment: .loadingUl {
width: 80%;
position: absolute;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
border-bottom: 15px solid brown;
-webkit-appearance: none;
border-radius: 100%;
animation: plate 1s linear infinite;
}

Answer (score -1):

Use -webkit-appearance: none; in css

Comment: Nopes nothing happens still i have that thin circular ring behind.

Comment: -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0;

Comment: border-radius:0; will flatten the ui